# After restarting Apache IoTDB, why the system still prompted 6667 configuration port is occupied?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I have just restarted my computer to try to startup Apache IoTDB, and seems like the error information still prompted that the 6667 port, that I configured the Cli tool of Apache IoTDB, is already occupied. I thought the cli should be run alone, so I don't know why this error happened and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message seems like to mean that your Apache IoTDB server is not started, therefore the client, which the Cli tool relies on running, cannot be connected. The client can connect to the server of other devices, but IoTDB must be started first. Try to start you IoTDB server first and see if you can connect this time.